# Swift - Call segue inside of a closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue, alamofire

I am trying to call a segue inside of a closure and I can't seem to make it work. The problem is that I don't know how to make the "performSegueWithIdentifier" call since I cannot use the keyword "self" here.

This is being done outside of UIViewController, so I don't know how to call a "performSegueWithIdentifier" without using the keyword "self".

So I would need to create the object where the method is called, but how and which object? Is it the view controller? On the storyboard? or where is it?

```
func signUp (username: String, password: String) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://test.xyz.de/api/v1/public/user", parameters:["username" : username, "password": password], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON({ (_, _, JSON, error) -> Void in
            println("Response: \(JSON)")
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToNextScreen", sender: self) // Problem!!
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        })
}
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need further explanation.

Cheers,
Tiago

Comment: You could use NSNotificationCenter to register a UIViewController to the notification that you will post from your class.

Comment: Are you using anything like a tabBarController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is being called from outside a view controller, the question becomes how is it being invoked?  The most appropriate solution is probably to add a parameter that takes the view controller it's being invoked from, since any segue can only happen relative to that view controller.

```
func signup(username:String, password:String, presentingViewController:UIViewController) {
    ...
        presentingViewController.performSegue("segueToNextScreen")
    ...
}
```

A better approach might be to actually pass in a success block, and then the caller could handle success by performing the appropriate segue.  That way your not dependent on any possible caller having a `segueToNextScreen` method and your separating network interface functionality from user interface functionality, always a good idea since they're really very distinct creatures.

```
func signup(username:String, password:String, success:()->()) {
    ...
        success()
    ...
}

// in calling ViewController
    signup(username, password) {
        self.performSegue("segueToNextScreen")
    }
```

Of course, the most obvious solution may be to just put this code into your UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 3):

```
func signUp (username: String, password: String) {

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://test.xyz.de/api/v1/public/user", parameters:["username" : username, "password": password], encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON({ (_, _, JSON, error) -> Void in
        println("Response: \(JSON)")

        if error == nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToNextScreen", sender:self)
                }
        } 
        else {

            println(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Encapsulating "performSegueWithIndentifier" inside "dispatch_async" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function which you will call inside the block which will perform the seuge. That way you can use the `self` keyword:

```
func performSegue(identifier:String){
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: self)
}

func signUp (username: String, password: String) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://test.xyz.de/api/v1/public/user", parameters:["username" : username, "password": password], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON({ (_, _, JSON, error) -> Void in
            println("Response: \(JSON)")
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue("segueToNextScreen") // Problem!!
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am not calling this function in the UIViewController, so the keyword "self" is not working. I am making a "Router" file and I'd like to call the segue from there, do you have any idea how? If I leave this performSegue function in UIViewController and call it from the closure, I still have no idea how can I access it.

Comment: Is signUp called from with in your VC? If so you could just pass the instance of your VC into signUp.

Comment: @boidkan yes. But how would I reference a VC then?

Comment: @iagomr Well if signUp() is being called inside your vc then you could do something like:

`func signUp(username:String,passwoprd:String,vc:UIViewController){<code here>}` and call it as `signUp(username,pw,self)` since self would be the instance you are using of the VC.

Answer (score 1):

Just call self before performSegue and you can call self again inside the method

**SWIFT 5**

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "resultViewController", sender: self)
```